# how does one re-schedule a powershell job within the powershell job?

Tags: powershell

I have written the following powershell script but it does not work. Specifically, it does not re-run the script the second time.   I understand that it needs to be run with administrator privileges, which I do.

```bsh
$online = CheckIfIamOnline
 if ($online) {
     Write-Host "You are currently online."
     # DO SOMETHING HERE
 }
 else {
     Write-Host "You are currently not online.  Scheduling check for later"
     $job = Get-ScheduledJob -Name DelayedJobTesting 
     $thisScript = $PSCommandPath
     $trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddMinutes(1)
     if ($job -eq $null)
     {
        Write-Host "Creating scheduled job"
        $job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name DelayedJobTesting -FilePath $thisScript -Trigger $trigger -
     }
     else {
        Write-Host "Updating scheduled job"
        $job | Set-ScheduledJob -FilePath $thisScript -Trigger $trigger | Format-Table -AutoSize
     }
     $job | Get-JobTrigger | Format-Table -AutoSize

 }
```

The above code works for the first time but not the second.  What am I doing wrong?   If I am running at first with "Run as Admin" how can I pass that along to the job being created?  I do not want to place any credentials in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you are touching scheduled job it will be interrupted (if running). Not sure it's the best workaround, but you can try to create a new job with similar name and then remove the old one at the end.  I guess you also need to use absolute path for your script, because PS scheduled job is executed as inline command. Or just use scriptblock instead of file.

```
 $jobName = "TestJob"
 $thisScript = "$home\Documents\sch.ps1"

 # .....

 $online = $false

 # .....

 If($online) { Write-Host "Success" } Else {

   Write-Host "rescheduling"

   $job = Get-ScheduledJob -Name "$jobName*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # get old job

   $trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddMinutes(1)
   Register-ScheduledJob -Name "$jobName$((get-date).Ticks)" -FilePath $thisScript -Trigger $trigger # create new job

   if($job) {$job.Remove($true)} # remove old job

 }
```